# Query post based on month and date

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm building company intranet on WordPress. I'm trying to get upcoming birthday list (for the next 30 days from current day), the birthdays' value is coming from a custom field with the Ymd format.

This code is returning all birthdays:

```
$args = array(
            'post_type' => 'employees',
               'meta_key'  => 'birthday',
               'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
               'order'     => 'ASC',
               'compare' => '>=', 
               'type' => 'DATE',
            );
```

I want to get only upcoming birthdays for one month period.

Comment: are you looking for current month or next 30 days?

Comment: What have you tried? Provide us with your code. This is just an array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your query based until the date you need. So you could do something like:

```
$start_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('- 1 month')); // or $start_date = date('Y-m-d');
$end_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+ 1 month')); // or '+ 30 days' for example
```

You can use `$start_date` and `$end_date` to get a specific date range in your query.

Remember when you use `date` AND/OR `strtotime` you can only go up to somewhere in 2038, if im correct. If you want to have dates AFTER 2038 you need to use the `new DateTime` function. (http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php)

Comment: I've found a current month solution.

Comment: Nice found! :). If my answer was not the answer on your question, you could add your own answer and mark it as the answer within 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a current month solution.

```
                $current_month = date('m');
                $filter_month = $current_month; // show current month only

                $args = array (
                  'post_type'      => 'employees', // your custom post type
                  'meta_key'       => 'birthday',  // your custom date field name
                  'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
                  'order'          => 'ASC',
                  'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                      'key'      => 'birthday',
                      'compare'  => 'REGEXP',
                      'value'    => '[0-9]{4}' . $filter_month . '[0-9]{2}',
                    ),    
                  )
                );

                $posts = get_posts($args);
```